# Woocommerce with Polylang not showing product discount on second language

Tags: woocommerce, polylang

I have an online store in two languages ​​that has been published for some time.
When applying a direct discount to products, it appears correctly in the main language but the discount does not appear on products when the second language is selected.
Last month I didn't have this problem, as the applied discount appeared in both languages, but now it no longer appears.

The plugins I am using are:

- WooCommerce
- Polylang
- Theme and plugin translation for Polylang (TTfP)
- Hyyan WooCommerce Polylang Integration

Does anyone know why this problem started happening?

En version where the problem is happening: https://squadporto.com/en/join-workout/

Thank you!!

I updated all the plugins and it continues to happen.
Disabled them all and turned them back on.
I can only edit prices or discounts in the main language version of the products, not allowing these values ​​(prices) to be edited on the second language product page.